# I am trying to specify a fixed digit "04" at the binning of a phone number in a Regular expression and a max digit of "10"

Tags: asp.net

I know that the following code allows me to enter a @ sign in the beginning followed by 10 digits.

```
\@\d{10}
```

but what i want is a 04 in the beginning followed by the 10 digits.but the following code does not work.

```
\04\d{10}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

`"(04)\\d{10}"`

It's allow enter 04 + 10 digits.

Comment: I think you ment to write "(04)\d{10}". I think by mistake you wrote an extra "\" . Thanks for your answer it was really helpful and did work.

Answer (score 0):

`/^(04)\d{10}$/` should meet your need.